# Websockets multiple events sent and multiple event handlers on client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

Recently I started using WebSockets for Server-Client communication. The problem is when I want to send multiple types of data in a connection. Is there any way to send multiple messages events from server side to client side in a single connection and to handle them separately in the client side?
Like...

```js
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws){ 
  ws.send('message1',data1);
  ws.send('message2',data2);
  ws.send('message3',data3);
}
```

Data1,2,3 are different types of data(data1 is a json, data2 is a string) and I want to use them in the client side for different purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a structure which every message follows and attach the type to this structure:

```js
wss.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'firstName', value: 'John' }));
wss.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'lastName', value: 'Doe' }));
```

Then handle the message by checking the type:

```js
wss.on('message', ev => {
  const data = JSON.parse(ev.data);
  switch (data.type) {
    case 'firstName':
      document.getElementById('first-name').textContent = data.value;
      break;

    case 'lastName':
      document.getElementById('last-name').textContent = data.value;
      break;

    default:
      // Unknown websocket message type
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok, so how do i get these messages events separately in client side?

Comment: I will try it, thx, I will let you know if it's working!

Comment: update: you re a life saver, I wouldn't have thought about this method. Thx a lot!